# Striped 2 color background with or without images?

Tags: css

I want to create a nice striped diagonal or horizontal background (yellow and black) for http://www.hallmorkshoneybess.co.uk but can't find any tutorials on how to do it.

Can you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ here are some excellent samples that you can use.

CSS3 isnt 100% accepted therefore, I would stick with something like http://www.stripegenerator.com

Answer (score 4):

From what Crinsane said you can do it like this:

`background-color: black;
 background: linear-gradient(white 50%, black 50%);
 background-size: 100% 20%;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;`

So basically we're creating a linear gradient of half black and half white, we then define its size as 20% of its container. So finally when we repeat it we get several stripes.

Change the 20% for different sized stripes, and the 50% 50% ratio for a different ratio of the 2 colours.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of css3 linear-gradients and background-size & repeat.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily do this using a linear-gradient with color-stops: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/css3-gradients-setting-color-stops/937

Comment: how would I do it with images?

Comment: if your stripes should be 2px wide and vertically, create an image which is 4px wide and 1px high with 2px of each color. then add it as background-picture and set it to repeat both x and y.